# How to load images and videos in RecyclerView from gallery in Android?

Tags: android, gallery, android-recyclerview

I am trying to load images, videos and whatever the screenshots into `RecyclerView` from Gallery. When click on the `RecyclerView` item need to highlight with listselector and need to get the list of selected paths. can any one suggest to do this. Like the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For multiple image picker, follow this link
[DroidNinja Filepicker](https://github.com/DroidNinja/Android-FilePicker)

Make Adapter and POJO class to view those selected photo on RecycelrView

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FilePickerConst.REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                filePaths.addAll(data.getStringArrayListExtra(FilePickerConst.KEY_SELECTED_PHOTOS));
                Image img;
                ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    for (String path : filePaths) {
                        img = new Image();
                        img.setUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
                        Log.e("VIDEO", Uri.fromFile(new File(path)) + "");
                        images.add(img);
                    }
                    rvPhoto.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, images));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
            break;
           }
```